# Erroneous red button on "review queues" and "suggested edits" icons

Tags: bug

Whenever I play HSM, the red dot for the "review queues" is lit up; when I click there, I see that the "Suggested edits" queue has a red dot.  When I click that queue, I'm told that the queue is empty.  This happens multiple times a day. This does not match the behavior on other SE topics, where the red button is lit only when there is actually something in a queue.  Whenever I see the red button, I think: "wow! SE wants my input", but on HSM it turns into "wow, HSM/SE is a tease"!

Sorry if this is not the right place to bring this up.

Comment: Hello World; now I am with you as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect what you are seeing is not technically a bug, but a limitation of the Stack Exchange software. To cut down on page load times, the review queue icons on top bar only keep track of the number of items present, but not what type. That means if there are items in the edit queue which you do not have the privileges to review edits on, you may see a red dot indicating this but when loading the queue have nothing to review. In particular, you don't yet have 1.5k reputation to [review tag wiki edits](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits), so if these items are in the queue this situation can occur. Based on the review history that appears to me to be what happened in this case. Even with that privilege this situation can still occur in some corner cases though, such as when you have reviewed every item but additional users' input is also needed to remove the item from the queues.

This has been reported many times on the main SE meta; see for example [Red Indicator Light Falsely Positive Most of the Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338688/red-indicator-light-falsely-positive-most-of-the-time). It is presently unclear whether they will make any changes to improve this issue, and if so what and when. In the meantime, there is not a lot that can be done to remedy this issue. If you get enough reputation to review tag wiki edits you would see this less often but it would still be a problem for other users between 1k and 1.5k reputation. I encourage all users with enough reputation to check the review queues regularly. With that said, this is not an especially large site and reviews can take a while to be completed. Personally I have been somewhat negligent in this, so going forward I will try to check the queues at least once a day.